# Trouble calling public function of namespace (coffeescript)

Tags: javascript, namespaces, coffeescript

This should be a really simple question, but I'm still having difficulty.

I have a namespace and a single member function as follows:

```
fb = 
    test1: ->
        console.log "test"
```

However, when I try to call the function in another file by using

```
fb.test1()
```

it doesn't recognize 'fb' as the namespace name. I have made sure that both files are sharing the same 'window' by making the proper inclusions.

EDIT:
this code worked with the function call:
    window.fb.test1()
and the namespace declaration:
    window.fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are doing this in the browser, try changing `fb =` to `window.fb =` and then see if you are able to find it in the "other file". You could also compile both files using `--join` or `--bare`, but be aware of the consequences.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to define a global namespace do it like this:

```
fb = window.fb ?= {}
```

You can spread such declaration across multiple files safely.